# R function periodReturn() not computing returns using adjusted closing prices

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod

I'm new to R and am having a difficult time using periodReturn() to compute annual total returns for VOO as the results appear different that what I would expect.

```
getSymbols("VOO", from = "2010-12-31")

returns <- periodReturn(VOO, period = 'yearly', type='arithmetic', leading = TRUE)

returns

           yearly.returns
2010-12-31    0.002437750
2011-12-30   -0.002084402
2012-12-31    0.134725864
2013-12-31    1.594722945
2014-12-31    0.113804320
2015-12-31   -0.007802553
2016-01-12   -0.050714152
```

Using 2015 as an example:

```
> VOO["2014-12-31"]

           VOO.Open VOO.High VOO.Low VOO.Close VOO.Volume VOO.Adjusted
2014-12-31   190.75   190.91  188.38     188.4    1365800     184.4854

> VOO["2015-12-31"]

           VOO.Open VOO.High VOO.Low VOO.Close VOO.Volume VOO.Adjusted
2015-12-31   188.12   188.76  186.93    186.93    2395200       186.93
```

This should result in a positive return for 2015 of 0.013251018 versus the -0.007802553 shown above.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain where you get 0.013251018 from?

Answer (score 1):

@Regressionman, I think ‘faking’ the original data is a terrible idea ! You loose data and destroy the OHLC structure. Why not use `endpoints` ? (it’s in the xts-package on which the quantmod-package you are using in your example is depending on)

```
> ROC(VOO$VOO.Adjusted[endpoints(VOO, on = 'years'),],type='discrete')
           VOO.Adjusted
2010-12-31           NA
2011-12-30   0.01897461
2012-12-31   0.15992784
2013-12-31   0.32386492
2014-12-31   0.12927916
2015-12-31   0.01325102
2016-01-13  -0.07393138
```

update regarding question concerning partial years:

To get partial year returns, where the 1st observation is not an endpoint, add the first obs to the endpoints like so:

```
ROC(VOO$VOO.Adjusted[c(1,endpoints(VOO, on = 'years')),],type='discrete')
```

Comment: I initially avoided endpoints because I was unable to determine how to get endpoints to work with securities not having a full year of prices, i.e. compute the partial-year ROC.  Is this possible?  I need to be able to compute partial-year returns in certain cases for the 8,000 tickers I process.  Thanks.

Comment: That should not be a problem as you can see above with the partial year 2016 which corresponds to YTD. Valid values for the argument `on` include: “us” (microseconds), “microseconds”, “ms” (milliseconds), “milliseconds”, “secs” (seconds), “seconds”, “mins” (minutes), “minutes”, “hours”, “days”, “weeks”, “months”, “quarters”, and “years” .

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough.  I was referring to the ROC for 2010 as  VOO starting trading on 2010-09-09.  I'd like to be able to include the partial return for 2010.

Comment: Thanks hvollmeier!  That was simple, resourceful, and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`periodReturn` only operates on closing prices.

The arithmetic is fairly simple, and it looks like you've done it for your example to get 0.013251018. So you could easily write a function to do it yourself.

Or fake it:

```
> VOO$VOO.Close = VOO$VOO.Adjusted
> periodReturn(VOO, period = 'yearly', type='arithmetic', leading = TRUE)
           yearly.returns
2010-12-31     0.81795783
2011-12-30     0.01897461
2012-12-31     0.15992784
2013-12-31     0.32386492
2014-12-31     0.12927916
2015-12-31     0.01325102
2016-01-12    -0.05071415
```